# Determine the third coordinate of a Right triangle for the given three sides and other two coordinates of triangle in 3D space?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, 3d, kinematics

I am dealing with marker data in 3D space. I have a right triangle made by the three points [A, B, C] where AC = Opposite, BC = Hypotenuse, AB = Adjacent. The objective is to find the coordinates of point C for the given :

- The x,y,z coordinates of the A and B are known
- The sides lengths AB, BC, and AC are also known
- Angle $\theta$ made between AB and BC are known
- The equation of the plane where the triangle lies in $ax+by+cz = d$ format

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VTx6.png)

I would like to know the most optimal method to find the coordinates of point C in 3D space.

Comment: I think this problem hasn't a unique solution. You can construct infinitely many different triangles from the data given. Coordinates for all possible $C$ will form a circle on a plane perpendicular to the one that contains $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding from my comment:

I think this problem hasn't a unique solution. You can construct infinitely many different triangles from the data given. Coordinates for all possible $C$ will form a circle on a plane perpendicular to the one that contains $A$ and $B$. Imagine the coordinates for $A$ and $B$ are $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0)$ respectively, the lengths $AB$, $BC$ and $AC$ are $1$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $1$ and $\theta=45$. Then $(1,1,0)$, $(1,-1,0)$, $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,0,-1)$ (among infinitely many others) would all be valid positions for $C$. Even in $\Bbb R^2$ you'd have two solutions for $C$.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the comment. I have updated my question description. We also have the plane equation on the which triangle would fall. Is there an optimal function we can write to get the C coordinates.

Comment: Even if you have the equation of the plane, there are two possible valid positions for C. This was what I was hinting at when I mentioned that even in $\Bbb R^2$ there are two solutions.